# Parsing a POST with JSON to display results to a user Swift 3.0

Tags: php, ios, json, swift3

I am creating an application that after a login occurs the user will be taken to a tab bar controller, on one of the tabs I want to display a user's profile that has data from a mySQL database. As of right now all I want to do is make the POST using my PHP get the JSON and display it to myself. I figure I could probably figure out how to display the data to a user from there. So far this is my profileViewController.swift page. I have everything in the viewDidLoad function because I want everything to be preloaded on the page when it is clicked. I am receiving a few errors. One error in my
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest){
line, and that error says "invalid conversion from throwing function of type'(*,*,_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?,URLResponse?,Error?)-> Void." The next error I have is in my "myJson" line and it says "computed property must have explicit type"

```
import UIKit

class profileViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var fNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var bDayLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var skillsLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var bioLabel: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {

        let request = try NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: phpurl)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        //Getting the values from the text fields and creating the post parameter
        let postString = "email=\(globalVariable.loginEmail)&password=\(globalVariable.loginPassword)"


        //Adding the parameters to request body
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        //Creating a task to send the post request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil{
                print("error is=\(error)")
                return;
            }

            let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data) as? [String: String]{

                print(myJson)
            }

        }
        task.resume()


    }

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: where are your text field outlet??

Comment: They are just text fields that are empty that I am going to change to the values I get from my json

Comment: "email=\(globalVariable.loginEmail)&password=\(globalVariable.loginPassword)" WHAT IS EMAIL AND PASSWORD HERE?

Comment: whatever the user had inputted when they logged in

Comment: are you sure you are getting email and password value here?

Comment: Yup, if I input the code from my login page I receive the same message in this view controller as I do in my login view controller

Answer (score 0):

swift 3.0 syntax should be like below

```
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {data,response,error in

        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        do {
            let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
            print("Result",resultJson!)
        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
```